# How to create a correlation matrix with significance levels in R?

Tags: r

I have a large data set and the function cor() doesn't help much to distinguish between high/low correlations.

Maybe someone can show me an example how to add colours or stars (* ** ***) or something to the correlation matrix, so I can easily see significant values?

Comment: have a look at the `corrplot`package : you can represent the correlation matrix graphically and show only the significant values

Comment: psych package is useful here `?psych::corr.test`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574670/corrplot-shows-insignificant-correlation-coefficients-even-when-insig-blank?answertab=votes#tab-top might be useful to help plot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971990/please-help-to-plot-pairwise-correlation#comment53773848_32971990 has some code to plot significance stars - it does need tidied up a bit

Comment: Wow, thanks! That corrplot thing is great.

Answer (score 1):

What about a `heatmap` ?

Imagine `mtcars` is your dataset.

You can transform the data as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282531/how-to-compute-correlations-between-all-columns-in-r-and-detect-highly-correlate)

```
ccor = cor(mtcars[,3:10]) # whatever variables 
cormatrix = arrange( melt(ccor), -abs(value) )
```

Then you can compute a nice heatmap, as explain [here](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/)

```
ggplot(cormatrix, aes(Var1, Var2) ) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue")
```

You get

[image]

Hope this help.

Also you can add the values with `+ geom_text(aes(fill = cormatrix$value, label = round(cormatrix$value, 1)))` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290364/heatmap-with-values-ggplot2).

Answer (score 0):

You can return the results of your correlations to a data frame, and then you can sort, subset, etc.

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

cor.list <- list(NULL)
length(cor.list) <- length(mtcars)^2

for(i in seq_along(mtcars)){
  for(j in seq_along(mtcars)){
    cor.list[[(i-1)*11 + j]] <- 
      tidy(cor.test(mtcars[, i], mtcars[, j])) %>%
      mutate(x = names(mtcars)[i],
             y = names(mtcars)[j])
  }
}

bind_rows(cor.list)
```