# How to know if a column is multiple of other?

Tags: python, r, excel, powerbi

How to know if a column is multiple of other?
How many registers of column sales are multiple of calls?

```
|Sales|Calls|
| 8   | 10 |
| 5   |  3 |
| 6   |  3 |
  ...
```

Been thinking a true or false solution and then counting how many true and false are

Been thinking about a boolean solution

Comment: You could calculate a correlation matrix for all your columns to see which have a correlation near 1. The closer it is to 1, the more precisely one column is a multiple of the other. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22282852/6851825

Comment: `data$Sales %% data$Calls == 0` ?

Comment: Or expanding that, `sum(Sales %% Calls == 0)` will count the number of rows where Calls is evenly divisable into Sales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @neilfws comment try this in Python:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sales': [8, 5, 6],
    'Calls': [10, 3, 3]
})

df["multiples"] = df['Sales'] % df['Calls'] == 0
print(df.multiples.sum())
```

Printout:

```
1
```

This only works if your data are integers. If you have zeroes in your counts you need to filter these beforehand.